# How to print a mult-line string with `putStrLn`?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a very simple program in Haskell that asks the user for a name and then displays some text based on that name.  I can get the program to work, but I would like to display an ASCII picture of a cat when the user inputs my cat's name.  I would like something such as

```
  ^  -  ^
 ( .   . )
   =>;<=
  /     \
 |       |
```

My "let's just see if this works" approach was to use putStrLn.  That doesn't work.  What can I do?  Thanks. My attempt

```
if name == "cat"
    then putStrLn ("      ^  -  ^
                         ( .   . )
                           =>;<=
                          /     \
                         |       |")
```

Comment: In what way doesn't `putStrLn` work?

Comment: @Lee I edited the question to show my naive attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lee asked "In what way doesn't `putStrLn` work?" and you responded with:

```
if name == "cat"
    then putStrLn ("      ^  -  ^
                         ( .   . )
                           =>;<=
                          /     \
                         |       |")
```

You should include the error messages.  Placing this in a top-level function (`test name = ...`) the code fails to compile with:

```
so.hs:3:38: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '\n'
```

That is because you can not have newlines in Haskell string literals. Multiline strings in Haskell require special escaping (backslash at the beginning and end of each line.  You already had an un-escaped backslash in your ascii art which should have been escaped, so we'll fix that too:

```
 test name =
        if name == "cat"
    then putStrLn ("      ^  -  ^\n\
                   \     ( .   . )\n\
                   \       =>;<=\n\
                   \      /     \\\n\
                   \     |       |")
```

Now we get another error because in Haskell `if` statements are more like the ternary operator and thus require an else branch to remain well typed.  The resulting code is:

```
test name =
        if name == "cat"
        then putStrLn ("      ^  -  ^\n\
                       \     ( .   . )\n\
                       \       =>;<=\n\
                       \      /     \\\n\
                       \     |       |")
        else return ()
```

Alternatively, you could use quasi-quoting for prettier multiline strings.  This requires the `string-qq` package and the quasiquotes language extension. The extension has syntax `[|<quoter name>|<string>|]` and the string-qq package provides a quoter named `s` for strings:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Data.String.QQ
import Control.Monad (when)

test2 name =
    when (name == "cat") $ putStrLn [s|
      ^  -  ^
     ( .   . )
       =>;<=
      /     \\
     |       ||]
```

Comment: I can get your second example to work.  Thanks.  When I try your third example, I am told it cannot find the module Data.String.QQ

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Did you install the `string-qq` package first?

Comment: I did not.  I will try to figure out how to do that.  These are my first couple of days learning to program.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another alternative, which I sometimes use:

```
putStr $ unlines 
  [ "      ^  -  ^"
  , "     ( .   . )"
  , "       =>;<="
  , "      /     \\"
  , "     |       |"
  ]
```

`unlines` is a standard function which takes a list of strings and concatenate them also inserting newlines after each string (including the last -- hence why I used `putStr` instead).

```
> unlines ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
"abc\ndef\nghi\n"
```